# Algorithm to scan a road network geometry using directions service

Tags: algorithm, routing, geometric-network

Let's suppose there's a Directions Service which, given a pair of points, returns the geometry, along the network, which best connects those points (which are previously projected - "snapped" - to the nearest road.

How could I solve the problem of, given a bounding polygon and a pair of initial points, perform iterative Directions Requests in order to find every road branch inside the bounding polygon?

I imagine, for example, for every route given, to take its endpoints, generate a circle of new points around it, request routes from the endpoint to each of these new points, and removing duplicate segments (this sounds tricky).

Is there any well-known way to perform this action, with no previous knowledge of either network geometry or topology?

Comment: Instead of a remote Directions Service you could traverse the network in your boundary via an offline solution like GraphHopper (warning: I'm the author) and fetch the network topology as well as the geometry

Comment: @Karussell the problem is: I don't have access to the network itself. When I start the algorithm, my boundary is "blank", and I can only find paths by poking (initially) random pairs of locations to see what comes up. The very idea is to discover the "hidden" road network.

Comment: But this 'discovery' is easily done when you traverse the graph around one location. But probably I do not really understand your problem (?)

Comment: @Karussell I cannot traverse the graph, because I don't have a graph. my starting point is not a "node", and I don't even get "nodes and edges" as a result of my routing request. The only way I have to interact with the (hidden) network is to ask for the closest path between two point, identical to what happens in Google Directions Service. After many requests, I will have a set of overlapping linestrings from which I could then infer the underlying geometry (and possibly topology)

Comment: That was the reason I was suggesting GraphHopper and OpenStreetMap